# CLI dotnet run with another command

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, command-line-interface, newman

I need to run the command line `dotnet run`, after starting the url localhost, I need to run another command like `curl`.

I could do like it:
`dotnet run & sleep 12; curl http://localhost:59406`

but if `dotnet run` delay more then 12 seconds, it will be stopped.

It may be possible to solve with linux commands, but I am not experienced in this.

If that helps, I will use this when building the Azure DevOps pipeline, to run newman tests on localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the sleep time if `dotnet run` takes longer to start up your application, to make sure your application is started when `curl` the url localhost

If you use this in azure devops pipeline, you can use two bash tasks to run above command. The first bash task run `dotnet run &` to start your application in the background. The second bash task run `curl` to curl url localhost. See below yaml pipeline example.

```
- bash: |
    #cd ConnectionWeb/ConnectionWeb
    #dotnet restore

    dotnet run & 

- bash: |
    curl http://localhost:8881
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your example but it didn't work. When it execute `curl` the localhost is not available.

Comment: Maybe the application process in the background got killed when the bash shell closed. But i tested on both my local agent and cloud agent, above script worked fine. You can have a try running the application with `nohup`. eg `nohup dotnet run &`